# Android : Image is not fitting correctly imageView when loaded with Glide

Tags: android, listview, android-glide

I am trying to load an image into an imageView that's in a listview's cell with Glide.

Here is the XML for the image view :

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_margin="2dp"
   android:scaleType="centerInside"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

And in the getView of my adapter:

```
Glide.with(activity)                           
 .load(url)
 .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
 .into((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView));
```

However, when the images first finish loading, they are not fitting the image view as they should. For example:

[image]

But then when I scroll the listview and come back to the image, it's being correctly rended:

[image]

What to do here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add `.dontAnimate()` after`.load()`

Comment: Was the solution. Thank you !